# services.node.ports must be a list

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, port

my docker-compose.yml file like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis'
  node:
    build: .
    ports:
      -"8082:8080"
```

I compile use docker-compose up

I got an error like this

```
services.node.ports must be a list
```

How can I fix this error msg. anyone can help me?

Comment: Put a space in between `- "8082:8080"`; the missing space is confusing the YAML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add some spacing between "-" and "8082:8080"

Your docker-compose.yml should look like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: 'redis'
  node:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
```